# Java BorderLayout PAGE_END overwrites SOUTH

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I have a strange problem.
I wanted a date be displayed in the bottom right of my panel.
The problem was, no matter how much I split up the south panels, it wouldn't be in the bottom right, so I found the PAGE_END placement. This works.
The problem is, that every JPanel .SOUTH is overwritten somehow, even if there is more than enough space for it.

Code is partially in german, so to avoid confusion, here is an abstract:

JPanel south has 3 Buttons which are displayed in the center.
JLabel date is 10 characters long and used with the Main JPanel.PAGE_END

[image: Without the PAGE_END JLabel]

[image: ONLY change is the JLabel added to MainJPanel.PAGE_END]

edit:
[image: This is how it looks without PAGE_END]

> public class bsp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1200,600);
    JPanel panelall = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelsouth = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelsouthsouth = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelsoutheast = new JPanel();
    
    
    
    panelall.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panelsouth.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panelsouthsouth.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panelsoutheast.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Button3");
    
    JLabel bottomright = new JLabel ("I should be even further in the bottom right corner");
    
    panelsoutheast.add(bottomright,BorderLayout.EAST);
    panelsouthsouth.add(button1);
    panelsouthsouth.add(button2);
    panelsouthsouth.add(button3);
    panelsouth.add(panelsoutheast,BorderLayout.EAST);
    panelsouth.add(panelsouthsouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panelall.add(panelsouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(panelall);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    

}
```

}

Comment: Please add your code here. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Regarding the issue itself, have you tried nesting `JPanel`s to achieve what you want?

Comment: well I posted the code... but its a pretty big mess, since I am just experimenting with stuff.

Comment: *I still cannot manage to get the date to appear in the bottom right corner* - and you still haven't posted your [mre]. We can't guess what you are doing in your code.  *I'll have to look it up somewhere else* Or you take 5 minutes to create this example. That is not an unreasonable amount of time to spent given how much time you have already spent. The point of the "MRE" is to simplify the code to make sure you understand the question you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

## You shouldn't mix absolute and relative positioning constants

Sorry it didn't ring a bell earlier, but the [`BorderLayout` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) is pretty clear on it:

> **Mixing both absolute and relative positioning constants can lead to unpredicable results.** If you use both types, the relative constants will take precedence. For example, if you add components using both the NORTH and PAGE_START constants in a container whose orientation is LEFT_TO_RIGHT, only the PAGE_START will be layed out.

The absolute positioning constants are `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, and `WEST`. The relative positioning constants are `PAGE_START`, `PAGE_END`, `LINE_START`, and `LINE_END`. Don't mix them: if you start with one type, keep using it.

If you want to have something like this:

```
+---------------+
| HEADER        |
+---------------+
| MAIN CONTENT  |
+---------------+
| FIRST FOOTER  |
+---------------+
| SECOND FOOTER |
+---------------+
```

Use the following kind of code:

```
JPanel mainPanel = getContentPane();
JPanel footerPanel = new JPanel();

mainPanel.add(new JLabel("HEADER"), NORTH);
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("MAIN CONTENT"), CENTER);
mainPanel.add(footerPanel, SOUTH);
footerPanel.add("FIRST FOOTER", NORTH);
footerPanel.add("SECOND FOOTER", SOUTH);
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot. Yea I figured it was some weird behaviour by mixing those two... but didn't know what.

The Problem is, that I tried that before.
I tried it your way, split up the "SECOND FOOTER" into borderlayout and told "SECOND FOOTER.SOUTH" to add the label.

But it was always just right next to the buttons. 

Could you give me an example that should work? (To put it in the bottom right instead of south, east)

I've added another picture to the main post so that you can see what it looks like if I split south into east,east.

Comment: *"I figured it was some weird behaviour by mixing those two..."* It's in no way weird. The `LINE..` / `PAGE..` constants are meant for *localized adjustment* between languages which are left-to-right (e.g. English) or right-to-left (e.g. Arabic) In English, the `LINE_START` corresponds to `WEST`. In Arabic, it corresponds to `EAST`. (And of course, only one component can be in any constraint of a `BorderLayout`..)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I still cannot manage to get the date to appear in the bottom right corner with the borderlayout, pls help

Comment: @Razak You removed your code. How can we know what's wrong with it if you remove it?

Comment: because it is convoluted. I just want an example of how to put a Label on the far bottom right (as you see in Pic2), without it overwriting my "South"Panel. That is all.

Comment: @Razak Asking for examples is contrary to Stack Overflow's rules. The website is for "I have a problem, please help me fix it", instead of "Please show me available solutions".

Comment: my original problem was solved. I now know that it was a conflict between BorderLayout.SOUTH and BorderLayout.PAGE_END.

The question is: "How would I do it so that I have the same effect as PAGE_END without this conflict." This is not "Do it for me". This is "I realize the issue, but have no clue how else to do it, because the method that SHOULD work (from my understanding) doesnt.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to start your problem from scratch. I'll load it into my IDE, make it work, run it, etc. this is why we request you to post your code. Your time is precious, mine is too.

Comment: trust me when I tell you that this is a simple question and trying to understand my code would take 500x longer.
That is why it is not there anymore. I WAS considering your time (and mine too because copying the relevant parts takes ages). 
But nvm... guess I'll have to look it up somewhere else.

Comment: @Razak *because copying the relevant parts takes ages* - Your application code is irrelevant to the problem. To demonstrate your problem all you need is a JFrame with a BorderLayout and then you add a JLabel to the "PAGE_END".

Comment: took me a while (I am still very new to coding), but I have now added the code to the original post. 
And as you can see, it is not in the corner. It is close, but not totally.